# Ubuntu 13.04 and AMD proprietary graphics drivers with PPA

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, ppa, proprietary

I want the AMD proprietary graphcis drivers installed via PPA. I don't want to install it manually because of updates. The open source drivers are not good for me because Unity is not smooth then.

My question is can I just click this to install the proprietary amd drivers? Is it bad when switching the points there without uninstalling something or does Ubuntu uninstall it automatically when switching a PPA driver?

[image]

Is this driver from AMD? I clicked on it and it did everything automatically. Did I have to uninstall something before or is it not bad when switching this from one point to another? And are these drivers exactly the same as from the website?

Edit: Push :)

Comment: does no one know?

Comment: It says proprietary there.  That generally means the proprietary drivers from AMD.

Comment: This driver is seriously outdated.